# Search nested array in lodash/es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Looking to search a value in an array of array and returning index. Most of the answers are array of objects. So I am looking to search for eg 22 and get 2 as the index where the value was found

Here is the code pen
https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-playground-array-pzzhe

```js
const arr = [["a","b"],["f","r"],["r",22,"t"]];
console.log("arr", arr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take plain Javascript with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [["a", "b"], ["f", "r"], ["r", 22, "t"]],
    value = 22,
    index  = array.findIndex(a => a.includes(value));
    
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const arr = [["a","b"],["f","r"],["r",22,"t"]];
console.log(arr.findIndex(a => a.includes(22)));
```

**Option 2**: Use functions [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const arr = [["a","b"],["f","r"],["r",22,"t"]];
// find element
const element = arr.find(a => a.includes(22));
// find element index
const currentIndex = arr.indexOf(element)

console.log(currentIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
indexOfFlat = (val, array) => array.findIndex(_arr => _arr.includes(val));
const arr = [["a","b"],["f","r"],["r",22,"t"]];
console.log("arr", arr);
console.log("index", indexOfFlat(22, arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would actually need the sub-array in which the value was found, you could also use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and its `index` and get both:

```js
const arr = [["a","b"],["f","r"],["r",22,"t"]];

let index, subArr = arr.find((x,i) => x.includes(22) && ~(index=i))

console.log('sub-array: ', subArr)
console.log('index: ', index)
```